# What's difference "a method with a finite number of steps" and "iterative method" in numerical linear algebra?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've been studying Numerical Linear Algebra, Lloyd, 1997. I've came across the below incomprehensible paragraph.

> "Methods like Householder reflections and Gaussian elimination would
>   solve linear systems of equations exactly in a finite number of steps
>   if they could be implemented in exact arithmetic. By contrast, any
>   eigenvalue solver must be iterative. The goal of an eigenvalue solver
>   is to produce sequences of numbers that converge rapidly toward
>   eigenvalues."

In the above, the author differentiates between "a method with a finite number of steps" and "an iterative method",but it seems to me that these words have similar meaning. Could anyone elaborate difference?

Comment: I would guess the author meant a known number of steps rather than finite.

Comment: An iterative method means that it constructs a sequence that converges to the solution and then stops the procedure after some finite but generally unknown *a priori* number of steps, resulting in an approximate solution to the problem.

Comment: It is a bit like saying a finite probability. Usually when people use the term they mean a non zero probability, as all probabilities are finite.

Comment: One thing is sure, no working algorithm has ever taken a non finite number of steps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

An iterative method involves creating a sequence of estimates that converge to the desired result, often employing some kind of recursively-defined sequence. A classic example is [Newton's method](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method), which takes a differentiable function $f$, an initial point $x_0$, and defines a sequence
$$x_{n+1} = x_n - \frac{f(x_n)}{f'(x_n)},$$
a sequence which (often) converges to a root of the function $f$. There is no guarantee that $f(x_n) = 0$ for any particular $n$, but $f(x_n)$ will (in many circumstances) become closer and closer to $0$.

Compare this to a method like Gaussian elimination. When applied to an $n \times m$ matrix, it takes no more than $n^2$ row operations before the matrix is in its unique reduced row-echelon form. We don't get convergence to the matrix we want, instead we get exactly the matrix we want, within a finite number of steps.

I hope that this clears things up.

Answer (score 2):

A method/an algorithm with finite number of steps is one, that if executed on a machine which can work with real numbers (and do addition and multiplication of real numbers), at some point stops, and the returns the exact result.

For example determining the determinant of a matrix using LR-decomposition will stop at some point, because there's nothing to do anymore.Now, if you wouldn't have made rounding errors, your result would be exact.

On the other hand, an iterating algorithm is one, which even if the machine would work on the real numbers, doesn't have the guarantee that it will ever find the exact result. 
Instead, the algorithm guarantees, that the iterations (from some point on) will get closer and closer to the exact result.